# Best way to show realtime data in iOS with Charts API

Tags: ios, swift, charts, linechart

I know there are some posts about it but I can't find something useful. Therefore, I'm opening new post. I have a device which sends some values over bluetooth. I have function which gets this value like every second. I need to show this data in line chart realtime (Two line). I know Android API has a function for realtime but I can't find it in iOS API.

How I'm doing now is like this;

```
if (uuid == kUUIDECGSensor) {
    let dataDict: [AnyHashable: Any] = LBValueConverter.manageValueElectrocardiography(dataValue)
   // print("kUUIDECGSensor dict: \(dataDict)")

    let allValues = Array(dataDict.values)
    print(allValues)
    data_array1.append(allValues[0] as! Double)
    data_array2.append(allValues[1] as! Double)
    //print(data_array1)
    //print(data_array2)
    temp_time += 5
    time.append("\(temp_time)")
    setChart(dataPoints: time, values: data_array1)
}
```

It is working but It doesnt seem like realtime. What am I missing?

Thank You!